# Reading Comprehension for MCAT (how to understand this sentence)

Tags: sentence, reading

At the same time, many architectural critics seem to be convinced that the present call for sustainability with its "green buildings" is but another screen behind which well-known old power structures hide.

From this sentence I don't really understand this part "...but another screen behind which well-known old power structures hide."

I am guessing that whole sentence is saying many arch. critics are convinced that present need for sustainability is not a lie (true).

Could someone please help me understand this sentence?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tricky part may be that the sentence contains a less-common use of "[but](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but)" where it serves as an adverb meaning "merely" or "only". (Example: "He is but a child.") In addition, "screen" is being used as a metaphor in conjunction with "hide". Therefore, another way of expressing the same meaning could be

> Many architectural critics seem to be convinced that the present call for sustainability (with its "green buildings") is **merely** another disguised opportunity for the same well-known power structures.

or

> Many architectural critics seem to be convinced that the present call for sustainability (with its "green buildings") is **nothing more than** a hidden application of the same well-known power structures.

So I'd reach the opposite conclusion as you: The author is saying that many critics think that the idea of architectural sustainability *is* a lie in some sense.